# Where can I find a zip.exe (that works in Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, zip, openoffice, sdk

I am trying to get the OpenOffice SDK installed. Its requirements are a number of programs

I ran into a "simple" problem: I can't find a zip program !

Quote:

> zip tool (2.3 or higher)
>
> The zip tool is used to create UNO packages. zip is a new requirement
>   to make the SDK independent of a Java SDK. If you do not have these
>   already, you can download them from http://www.info-zip.org. Note: The
>   cygwin zip.exe does not work for the build under the 4NT shell. You
>   have to use the native w32 version.

I have tried - but the link above sends me to downloads of  [zip binaries](http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html) that show "frozen"

Anything else I have tried - like 7zip or winrar - is rejected by setup program, which looks for "zip.exe"

Please, where can I find a zip.exe (that works in Windows 7) ?

Comment: Your link to the installation guide points to the file on your computer.  You should remove the link, or change it to a website.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I did not notice that the link was from a document contained in the installed SDK.

Comment: If you have Chocolatey: `choco install zip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you scrolled down another dozen lines, you would have found the link to their FTP server and their SourceForge page:

ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/

EDIT:  Step-by-step to get zip.exe file:

- Go to [FTP server](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/).
- Click on the system you need.  Use "win32" folder for Windows.
- Click on the version of Zip that you need.  Version 3.0 is the latest version.  For 64-bit, select the x64 file.
- Download this zip file.
- Extract the zip file to the location of your choice.
- Extract the extracted zip file to the location of your choice.
- Use zip.exe as needed.

Comment: I have tried... the only binaries I found were a zip3.0.exe that was rejected by the bat file... the alternative would be to build it myself ?

Comment: Really?  I just downloaded Zip 3.0 and it contains a zip.exe just as requested.  Edited my answer for step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but I figured that it would be nice to have a direct copy of `zip.exe` made available

https://github.com/tisaconundrum2/zip

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here:

https://www.willus.com/archive/zip64/

(64 bit Zip 3.1c02 BETA)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which comes with a recent `zip.exe`

```
# c:\cygwin64\bin\zip --version
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
Currently maintained by E. Gordon.  Please send bug reports to
the authors using the web page at www.info-zip.org; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip,
as of above date; see http://www.info-zip.org/ for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 11.3.0 for Unix (Cygwin) on Jun 16 2022.
```

Answer (score -2):

From [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6dc3b0f6-f937-4569-a576-2e6cec2768f2/zipexe-in-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral):

> There is no zip.exe in Windows 7 and as far as I know there has never been a zip.exe in any version of Windows[...]

---

> According to what you wrote, that batch script uses a "zip.exe" file someway deployed on that system, maybe part of a file compression and archiving program.
>   There's no such a command available in a Windows installation.

---

Additionally, when I used [everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) (a program that searches every single file on your computer) to serach for `zip.exe`, nothing came up.

Comment: I found that question as well, i am not looking for a file installed on my machine as part of windows. I am trying to find a zip file on the internet. please see my question of things I have tried.

Comment: There is no zip.exe. It is a function of the file explorer.